# Why do I get a conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data warning?(c)

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm writing a program which basically calculates the duty on a car imported. The user is supposed to input the values the values for the price of the car and the shipment. But when I calculate I get this error which is not good.

//TOTAL DUTY TO BE CHARGED ON A CAR IMPORTED//

```
main()
{

        float purchaseprice, shipmentcosts, ecowaslevy, importlevy, GCNETlevy, TotalDuty;

        printf("Enter the purchase price and shipment cost");


        scanf("%f,%f", &purchaseprice, &shipmentcosts);
        ecowaslevy = 0.01f, importlevy = 0.25f, GCNETlevy = 0.05f;
        //FORMULAS FOR THE LEVY//
        ecowaslevy = (purchaseprice + shipmentcosts) * (0.01); 
        importlevy = (purchaseprice + shipmentcosts) * (0.25); 
        GCNETlevy =  (purchaseprice + shipmentcosts) * (0.05); 
        //FORMULA FOR TOTAL DUTY//
        TotalDuty = (ecowaslevy + importlevy + GCNETlevy)*(3.2);
        printf("TOTAL DUTY=GHC.%f", TotalDuty);
        system("pause");

}
```

These are the warnings:

> 1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\total expenses\total expenses\tot.c(9): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data

1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\total expenses\total expenses\tot.c(10): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data

1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\total expenses\total expenses\tot.c(11): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data

Comment: [sigh]..  which line generates the warning. Where are the var declarations and types?

Comment: Please show the variable definitions.

Comment: line (9) generates the warning.

Comment: what do you mean by variable definitions. I have defined my variables. all are float

Comment: sorry did not see the error

Comment: Don't get the warning and which line is line 9?

Comment: remember to append 'f' to all floating point literals you want to be `float`, without it they are `double`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In several lines you multiply by constant values like `0.01` and `0.25`. These values are doubles and the result of the multiplication is double which you then store in a float variable having less precision. This gives you a compiler warning. To fix it you can attach the `f` literal suffix to the constant values, e.g. `0.01f` and `0.25f` etc.

Comment: In my code i have attached it. Look at at. I still get the warning

Comment: @DavidAsmah: No, you clearly use the literal `0.01` in line 9 which is a double literal. Replace it with the float literal `0.01f` and the warning goes away. I just tested this myself.

Comment: but when i tested it i got a negative value, which is wrong

Comment: Why does the warning say "**possible** loss of data" though, surely it should know whether 0.01 can be represented as a float or not?

Comment: @riv The possible loss of data is when a `double` is stored in a `float` variable. This happens at run time and the compiler is emitting a warning about this. The compiler cannot at compile time know if the conversion loses precision. And the loss is **possible** because it doesn't happen all the time. `1d` converts to `1f` which is still just 1. However, 0.1 does not have an exact representation using a binary floating point number and `0.1d` is not quite the same number as `0.1f`. On my computer `0.1f - 0.1d` is 1.49011611383365×10⁻⁹.

Answer (score 1):

Because `sizeof(double) > sizeof(float)` and hence you loose precision.